# can't filter jQuery click off class definition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table set up... here is the relevant HTML format...

```
<table class="booking table">
   <tbody class="time_period_rows">
      <tr class>
        <td> ... </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="booked">
        <td> ... </td>
      </tr>
       .
       .
      <tr class="selected">
        <td> ... </td>
      </tr>
```

And the table goes on from there. Fundamentally I have table of appointment slots. The "booked" class means exactly that. The "selected" class is toggled on and off as a the time for a new booking is selected. I simply want to stop a click being recognised when they try and select one where the "booked" class exists. Here is my current jQuery code,

```
$('.time_period_rows tr:not(.booked)').click(function(){
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Pretty darn simple. But the filtering is not working. Right now I can select any row. Can anyone see why?

Many Thanks

Comment: Silly question, but you are using jQuery, correct? It's not part of your tags, and you make no mention of it. This syntax wouldn't work in pure JS.

Comment: Sorry, yes. I am using jQuery. Apologies.

Comment: Can you set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/RNrjc/

Comment: Agreed. It worked for me, as well. Not that it should matter, but simply out of pure curiosity, what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: 1.7.1... Umm. Strange. I need to investigate this a little further. I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: Guys, I set up a larger jsfiddle here... literally cut as pasted from the page viewed as source... the darn thing works in jsfiddle, but not in the real world...on chrome or firefox... any ideas why something could be working on jsfiddle and not elsewhere...? Thanks http://jsfiddle.net/areee/

Comment: Ignore my last comment. The answer below works. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.time_period_rows tr').on('click', function(){
    if (!$(this).is('.booked')) {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: God darn!!!! That works. Thank you! Can you briefly explain why your technique works and mine didn't? Thanks again

Comment: I would have believed that your selector should have done the trick, but since it didn't, trying a check with `is()` was my second option, and that seemed to work. Basicly it checks if it the `tr` has the class booked, but there is a not `!` in front so it turns the boolean around, sometimes that works a lot better then doing a bunch of stuff that will run thru sizzle (jQuery stuff), and `not()` doesn't always work either, but then suddenly `is()` with a not `!` in front will work ? Maybe someone with more knowledge about the inner workings of jQuery can explain exactly why it so ?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. And thanks for ending my misery with this problem! ;-) Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to unbind click as the `<tr>` have the class `booked` added:

```
$(this).unbind('click');
```

Comment: Sorry, can you explain that a little? I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: When you bind click to the rows that have the class `booked`, even if you change the class eliminating it from the initial selection it is still bound. You can unbind it when the class is changed or you can use the function @adeneo presented...